# Identify component marked β908 ER

Tags: identification, components

[image: β908 ER:]

This component is connected to the source of a high-side MOSFET, in parallel with the golden capacitor. One pin to the MOSFET source, and the other to a diode.

Which component is this, marked β908 ER?

Comment: The \$\beta\$ is likely for [Bourns](https://www.bourns.com).

Comment: Can it be an Bourns SMBJ170CA, SMB TVS diode of 170 V?
Does that fit with the mosfet ratings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [SMBJ170CA](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/SMBJ.pdf), a bidirectional TVS (Transient Voltage Suppressor) from Bourns. Check the table on the 2nd page.

**NOTE:** The package of the device you photographed seems like SMB or SMC, but the package given in the datasheet is SMB. If the one you have is SMC (wider than SMB) then it's possible that the component might be a bit old as the older productions may have a bigger package. You may want to compare the actual dimensions and the ones given in the datasheet.